# Learning linux and using shell script find

Tags: bash, shell

So I'm trying to build a script where it will search every file in the directory and it's sub-d, then it will delete all files that have `~` in the end of it and all files that have `#` in the end and at the beginning of it.

I was trying to first remove files with `~` then figure it out how to delete with both.

What I have for now is:

```
find -name "~" -delete
```

I've used this page as source
https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/find-files-in-linux-using-the-command-line/

It clearly does not work, I've tried `man find` and I'm struggling to find where this information is.

Comment: This question belongs on [unix.se], as it is an OS utility question and not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a wildcard to match other characters in the filename. Otherwise it's looking for a file named exactly `~`, not with `~` at the end.

```
find . \( -name '*~' -o -name '#*#' \) -delete
```

Comment: so the * before ~ and between #*# means what?
In the first case it would be after everything and in the other ignore everything in the between and only the first and last?

Comment: `*` is a wildcard that matches any sequence of characters. Like when you do `ls *.txt` to list all text files.

Comment: If you're going to put code in a comment, put it between backticks. Otherwise `*` is the markdown for italics and the code is unreadable.

Comment: Wildcards are something that most Unix users are familiar with, I didn't think I'd need to explain it in detail.

Comment: so I've tried your tip and it deletes the ones that has ~ in the end and both # in the begining and end of it.
For it to work the way i want it i hade to made it like this, but I believe that it has a less verbose way
`find . \( -name '*~' -o -name '#*#' -o -name '#*' -o -name '*#' \) -delete`

Comment: well i'm just begining to learn unix, it's my second day, so there are some things that I don't know already. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step-by-step:

1. Find all in `/path/to/dir`

   ```
   $ find /path/to/dir
   ```
2. Find all files in `/path/to/dir`

   ```
   $ find /path/to/dir -type f
   ```
3. Find all files in `/path/to/dir` that end with `~`

   ```
   $ find /path/to/dir -type f -name '*~'
   ```
4. Find all files in `/path/to/dir` that end with `~` or begin and end with `#`

   ```
   $ find /path/to/dir -type f \( -name '*~' -o -name '#*#' \)
   ```

   Here we use grouping to force precedence. Alternatively, this could read

   ```
   $ find /path/to/dir -type f -name '*~' -o -type f -name '#*#'
   ```

   Note: `expr1 expr2` reads `expr1` and `expr2`
5. Find all files in `/path/to/dir` that end with `~` or begin and end with `#` and delete them

   ```
   $ find /path/to/dir -type f \( -name '*~' -o -name '#*#' \) -delete
   ```

More information: `man find`

Comment: so the * before ~ and between #*# means what?
In the first case it would be after everything and in the other ignore everything in the between and only the first and last?

Comment: the same thing happened with your code, for some reason the ones starting with # and the ones ending with # are not being deleted 


`find . ( -name '~' -o -name '#*#' -o -name '#' -o -name '*#' ) -delete`

like this it worked fine, is there a way to make it less verbose?

Comment: asterisk is a wildcard (glob) and represents any string that does not contain a slash. To make it less verbose, you can remove the second case (`#*#`) as it is matched both by `*#` and `#*`

Answer (score 0):

If you have Bash 4.3 (released in 2014) or later, you don't need `find` to delete the files:

```
shopt -s dotglob globstar nullglob
rm -- **/*~ **/#*#
```

- `shopt -s ...` enables some Bash settings that are required by the code:

  - `dotglob` enables globs to match files and directories that begin with `.`.  `find` shows such files by default.
  - `globstar` enables the use of `**` to match paths recursively through directory trees.  This option was introduced with Bash 4.0 (2009) but it is dangerous to use in versions before 4.3 (2014) because it follows symlinks.
  - `nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).

The `**` globs can be used to do much more than apply a single command to all matching files.  For instance, to loop over all the matching files (and do whatever you want to each of them) use:

```
for path in **/*~ **/#*#; do
    # Process "$path" here
    ...
done
```

To make a list (Bash array) containing all the matching files (for later processing):

```
matching_files=( **/*~ **/#*# )
```

Note that there are several pitfalls associated with processing the output of `find` (e.g. looping over it, or converting it to a list), so using `**` globs can be a better option when they are applicable.

Comment: thanks, but the point of the exercise is not to only delete it, but to create a script were i would be able to find everything in a directory and delete it with those specifications

Comment: this is exactly what it is doing

Comment: @DanielFabre, I think the code in the answer does what you requested in the question.  In case there is something else you want to do with the matched files, I've added more information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

~$ or *~ // ending with ~

// Search all file ending with ~ and delete it

```
find <PATH> -name "*~" -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```